# SAP function MSQ_SPACE_DOWNLOAD

Tags: sap-basis

Does anybody have documentation of MSQ_SPACE_DOWNLOAD function? It's used to monitor SAP running on MSSQL server, but can't be found on some servers. I'm searching for what to switch on in SAP to enable it or any other information.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems, it was not officially released.